# eclipse java application program won't run - unverified user

Tags: eclipse, javaw

I get the following error when launching (Run > Run configurations > Java application) a java application called 'Simulator':

Launching Simulator has encountered a problem. Exception occurred executing command line.

In the details of the error message:

```
Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe" (in directory "D:Leerlingenversie"): CreateProcess error=1244, De aangevraagde bewerking is niet uitgevoerd omdat de gebruiker niet is geverifieerd
```

The last part of the message would translate to something like `'unverified user'`.

What is the problem here?

I ran an exact copy of the workspace on a different pc with the same Eclipse installed and there it would run just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I found that by placing the copy of the workspace in the root (D:) the issue was 'solved' (meaning the error no longer occurred, however not knowing what the problem actually was)